# Assumptions in multilevel model - what exactly should I be checking, and when?

Tags: mixed-model, assumptions

I'm currently trying to analyse data using multilevel modeling, and I'm struggling to get a clear picture regarding checking the assumptions. For context, in the experiment, participants were shown faces expressing different emotions, and each face was judged on eight different emotional scales. The point was to explore how the characteristics of the participant and of the perceived face influence perception of various emotions (for example, do people perceive male expressions as more angry than female ones?). This led to a rather complicated dataset...

The DV would be ratings on one of the eight emotional scales. We will treat each emotion separately, so there will be eight different models. There are two within-subject predictors - the perceived faces' gender and its type (real face vs avatar face). There are also two between-subject predictors - the participant's gender as well as a continuous measure of exposure to violent videogames (conceptualised as number of hours spent gaming per week on average). Then, there is the random effect of Participant ID and we're also considering including the stimulus ID as a random effect, since the perceived faces different in expressed emotion. This is problematic in itself since that random effect would be in itself fully explaining the effects of the face's gender, hence I am not yet entirely sure how the stimulus ID will be included. Nonetheless, I started reading about and running assumption checks, and found the literature to be rather inconsistent regarding what is essential in case of a multilevel model. My questions are therefore:

1. From what I understood, I need to check for normality, linearity, multicolinearity of the predictors, and the presence of outliers. Is that correct? I have seen that outliers are not always mentioned as a necessary check.
2. Do I have to check the assumptions BEFORE having built the model? Now, this one is really confusing as I would of course think to check the assumptions before even beginning to consider creating my model, however the majority of methods to check the assumptions in R relies on first having created the model and using it in the code to check assumptions. For example, the supposedly best/fastest way to check for multicolinearity is this kind of code:

   `check_collinearity(my.model)`

So, it seems I need to first have the model and then run the assumption checks. It feels rather counterintuitive to me and as such I wanted to confirm if it's correct.

3. Lastly, do I have to check assumptions on my random effects as well? In this case, this would be the Participant ID. If so, I'm unsure what kinds of assumptions should be checked? Despite having read dozens of blog posts and forum threads regarding MLM assumptions, all I found are some vague mentions of 'having to check assumptions for random effects' on a handful of pages, while majority does not indicate anything like that.

I would greatly appreciate any input, multilevel modeling is unfortunately way above my level of knowledge in stats, and it seems I simply won't figure it out on my own.

Comment: Assessing the adequacy of the distributional assumption about random effects is a good idea and requires lots of observations on lots of clusters to do so.  While thinking about that, think more about the easier problem of assessing distributional assumptions about Y given covariates.  The assumption of normal constant variance residuals may be suspect for your type of Y.   Consider multilevel proportional odds ordinal logistic models to relax these assumptions.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Yes I'm aware of the problem of my DV, while the discussion regarding using Likert scale as continuous seems to be unresolved, I definitely understand it's not ideal and can create issues... Thank you for your reply, I suppose I'll try discussing it with my supervisor again and see what I can do.